# Testng JavaScript callbacks

Tags: javascript

I fear I do not fully understand JavaScrpt variable scoping. I have a function that looks like this:

```
return {
  response: '',

  birthMonthPrompt: function(question, promptCallback) {
    this.dialogText = question;
  }
};
```

The idea is that birthMonthPrompt will ask a user for their birth month. After they enter it, I will have a value like 'November'. To test ths, I've written the following:

```
it('should prompt the user', function() {
  var reponse = 'November';
  myService.response= response;

  myService.birthMonthPrompt('Please choose your birth month:', 
    function(userResponse) {
    expect(userResponse).toBe(this.response);
    }
  );
});
```

When I execute this, I get an error that says:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: response
```

I don't understand why my test can't find response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, you also have to call the callback at some point (you don't seem to be doing anything with `promptCallback`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
var reponse = 'November';
```

Should be:

```
var response = 'November';
```

Comment: Don't forget to vote to close the question. We have a close reason for that.

Comment: doh! can't believe I didn't see that. Sometimes I miss my compiler :)